# XmlElement.Attributes is dropping namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, system.xml

If you prefer as a fiddle - [click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DiIv9I).

In my debugger, I have an XmlElement.OuterXml of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p:sld mc:Ignorable="p14 a14 p15 p16 a16 thm15 adec ahyp v"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:asvg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/SVG/main"
  xmlns:ahyp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2018/hyperlinkcolor"
  xmlns:adec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/decorative"
  xmlns:thm15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/thememl/2012/main"
  xmlns:p16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2015/main"
  xmlns:p15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2012/main"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main"
```

Note it's mc:Ignorable, not Ignorable.

I call XmlElement.Attributes and one of the attributes is for Ignorable but...
[image]

It's lost the prefix/namespace.

Any idea what is going on here?

Update: [I also posted on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e8fd119-8962-4210-8211-02dff6713bbc/xmlelementattributes-is-dropping-namespaces) as the answer here so far is it's a bug and I'm surprised something so basic would be wrong.

Comment: The prefix doesn't matter. It can be absolutely anything. The main thing is that the attribute has a namespace.

Comment: It's actually there.  If you generate the XML for the entire `XmlDocument doc` then you get `<inner mc:Ignorable="p14 a14 p15 p16 a16 thm15 adec ahyp v" />`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/v9v36E.  I'm not sure why the prefix isn't present in [`XmlAttribute.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattribute.name?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlAttribute_Name) since that's documented to return *The qualified name of the attribute node.*

Comment: Honestly, you should consider switching to [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview), it's just easier to work with. Its treatment of namespaces, notably, is a little simpler than `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

You may not get it directly as a part of name of the attribute. There is a property "Prefix" , which is expected to return but it is empty. But `GetPrefixOfNamespace` is returning the prefix properly after passing the attribute's namespace URI as input. Could be some implementation issue. So for now try as said below.

```
var list = inner.Attributes;
foreach (System.Xml.XmlAttribute attr in list)
    Console.WriteLine(attr.GetPrefixOfNamespace(attr.NamespaceURI) + ":" + attr.Name);
```